# concat Javascript objects with more than one key

Tags: javascript

is there a possibility way to easy concat javascript arrays?
Here is my code and it works, if nonPeriodicallySchedulesObject only has one key

```
var mergedObjects = schedulesObject[schedulesObjectKey].concat(nonPeriodicallySchedulesObject[nonPeriodicallySchedulesObjectKey]);
```

Currently I have the usecase that nonPeriodicallySchedulesObject contains more than one key:

> ['13', '3453']

Is there an easy and performant way to concat **schedulesObject[schedulesObjectKey]** and **nonPeriodicallySchedulesObject** with one or more than one key?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't get it, are you asking us if there is a better way to `newArray = oldArray.concat(suffixArray);`

Comment: What is not working? What happens? concat handles arrays or single items.

Comment: do you want a unique merge or just concatenation? i think you need a **union** (i.e unique merge), in this case one can do it in linear time, assuming the arrays are sorted, else in log-linear time (sort them first) else in quadratic time

Comment: Easy and preferred way is highly contingent on what you are looking to do to. You can always write a function that will concate multiple keys, but it all depends on what you need. do you need multiple keys of `schedulesObject[]` to be used? What about multiple keys of `nonPeriodicallySchedulesObject`... Is it always going to be 1 of the first keys combined with all keys of the next? Or will it be contingent on other factors? I suggest going into more detail to let us know exactly the scenario you are trying to solve, see our answers, and build upon that yourself.

Comment: Can't you just iterate through all the keys in `nonPeriodicallySchedulesObject`, calling `concat` on each one?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. To clarify my question: I need a merge (not a union!!) of **schedulesObject** and **nonPeriodicallySchedulesObject**. I think my current problem is, that the value of only key in schedulesObject is empty - therefore I get undefined for mergedObjects. It would be great if someone could post a suggestion for this problem. Thanks a lot!